# Is $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ a solvable group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

Recently we showed in class that the group $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ is not solvable since the commutator subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ is equal to $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $, implying that the group $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $ is not solvable. However, it involved some tedious calculations and correct guessing of the generators of $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) $.

Anyway, I was wondering whether we can reach the same conclusion for $SL_2(\mathbb{C}) $, meaning that $SL_2(\mathbb{C}) $ is also the commutator subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{C}) $ and thus not solvable.

Comment: You can reach the *analogous* conclusion for $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ by a *different* proof for $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ :)

Comment: Or just notice that ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb R})$ is a subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb C})$, and subgroups of solvable groups are solvable.

Comment: @DerekHolt if you make that an answer I would accept it to close the question

Comment: @DerekHolt:  Technically, the question in the second paragraph is whether the commutator of $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ is itself.  Even if $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ is not solvable, that leaves the possibility the commutator of $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ is some proper normal subgroup of $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ containing $SL_2(\Bbb{R})$.  There is no such subgroup, but $SL_2(\Bbb{R})$ being self-commutator is not a complete proof.

Comment: Yes I agree, my comment was not an answer to the question that was asked, it was indicating an alternative approach to the problem.

Comment: It's always tough to know what to do when the title question does not match the question in the post. I tend to go the other way: if the title question has a useful answer, it's worth making it an answer, even if it does not address the ins and outs of the post itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the proof works for **all fields** except for $\Bbb F_2$ or $\Bbb F_3$.

**Theorem:** Let $K$ be a field with at least $4$ elements. Then the group $SL_2(K)$ is perfect, i.e., its commutator subgroup equals $SL_2(K)$.

Proof: See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/perfect+group), Proposition $2.4$. Note that $SL_2(\Bbb F_4)\cong A_5$.

Answer (score 2):

Following @DerekHolt's suggestion, let $N$ be the commutator subgroup of $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$.  Then $SL_2(\Bbb{R})\subseteq N$ because $SL_2(\Bbb{R})$ is its own commutator subgroup and a subgroup of $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(i\theta)&0\\
0&\exp(-i\theta)
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1+I}{2}&\frac{-1+I}{2}\\
\frac{1+I}{2}&\frac{1-I}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1-I}{2}&\frac{1-I}{2}\\
\frac{-1-I}{2}&\frac{1+I}{2}
\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
This proves $\begin{pmatrix}\exp(i\theta)&0\\0&\exp(-i\theta)\end{pmatrix}\in N$ because $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\in SO(2)\subseteq SL_2(\Bbb{R})$ and the conjugation in $(1)$ is by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1+I}{2}&\frac{-1+I}{2}\\\frac{1+I}{2}&\frac{1-I}{2}\end{pmatrix}\in SU(2)\subseteq SL_2(\Bbb{C})$.

Next, Let $\lambda>0$ (in $\Bbb{R}$).  Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda&0\\
0&\frac{1}{\lambda}
\end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\Bbb{R})\subseteq N\tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1), (2)$,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda \exp(i\theta)&0\\
0&\lambda^{-1}\exp(-i\theta)
\end{pmatrix}\in N\tag{3}
$$

now let $A\in {SL}_2(\Bbb{C})$.  If $A$ is diagonalizable, then its eigenvalues are $\lambda \exp(i\theta), \lambda^{-1} \exp(-i\theta)$ for some $\lambda>0,\theta\in\Bbb{R}$.  Then $A$ is similar via some $S A S^{-1}$ to the matrix in $(3)$ for $S\in GL_2(\Bbb{C})$.  By multiplying $S$ by some complex scalar, we can get $\det(S)=1$ so $S\in SL_2(\Bbb{C})$.  Hence $A$ is a conjugate of the matrix in $(3)$ so $A\in N$.

Finally, if $A$ is not diagonalizable, its Jordan form is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
z&1\\
0&z
\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}
$$
where $z\in\Bbb{C}$ and $z^2=\det A=1$.  So $z\in\{\pm 1\}$ and the matrix in $(4)$ is in $SL_2(\Bbb{R})$ and therefore $N$.  By conjugation we again get that $A\in N$.  This completes the proof that $N=SL_2(\Bbb{C})$.